# How do I use MockContentResolver when testing an Android Activity using Espresso?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, ui-testing, android-espresso

I am using Espresso to test an `Activity` that displays data retrieved using a `ContentProvider`.

I'd like to mock the content provider using [MockContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContentProvider.html) and [MockContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContentResolver.html), but I don't know how to make the activity method `getContentResolver()` return a mock resolver.

(I could insert the data before executing the test, but I'd like to know if it is possible to use a mock provider instead)

UPDATE:
I still could not make it work, so I'm including some code to try to make it clearer.

MyActivity.java

```
MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    private delete(String id) {
       // The method getContentResolver() is what I want to mock when testing
       getContentResolver().delete(
           Contract.Item.makeUriForItem(id), null, null);
    }

    ...

}
```

MyActivityTests.java

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class StockChartDetailsActivityTests {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> myActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MyActivity>(
        MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

}
```

I could not make the suggestion to use Dagger2 to work because `getContentResolver()` is implemented by android and I can't use `@Inject` to inject my own `ContentResolver`.

I could use different strategies:

- inserting data in the database before testing.
- have another layer, like a business logic layer, and move calls to `getContentResolver()` to the classes in this layer and then I could inject (and mock) the business logic classes.

But before using any of these strategies I'd like to know if it is possible to use `MockContentResolver`.

Comment: Please include a code sample with your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Dependency Injection framework. I think that for Android a good choice is [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/).

Using Dagger, you can inject in your `Activity` your real Content Provider. A common way for injecting something in an Activity, is to use a field injection (because you cannot act directly on the constructor of the Activity: it is created by the system). So you can instantiate the Dagger module in the `Application` class, and get it from the `Activity` in order to inject itself. Something like:

```
((MyApplication).getMyComponent()).inject(this);
```

Your class `MyApplication` will contain something like:

```
MyComponent mMyComponent = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this)) // this is in general useful if you need a Context
                .contentProviderModule(new ContentProviderModule())
                .build();
```

And it has to include of course the `getMyComponent()` method for returning the module:

```
MyComponent getMyComponent() {
    return mMyComponent;
}
```

Now, that your module is injected in your Activity from the outside, you can easily inject something else for testing purpose:

In the /test/ folder and using the same path of your `MyApplication` class, you can create a new class that extends `MyApplication` and create your module passing a mocked version of the ContentProvider.

I cannot go through all the steps but you can take a look [here](https://github.com/ecgreb/dagger-2-testing-demo) for more details

Comment: Also check out Chiu-ki Chan's work. She uses Mockito and implements a custom runner to instantiate a mock application. http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/dagger-2-espresso-2-mockito.html https://youtu.be/JlHJFZvZyxw?t=23m38s

Comment: Can I inject something that is part of the Android framework, @GVillani82? What I'm trying to mock is the ContentResolver which I have access to by calling the method getContentResolver() on a context.

Comment: Yes, you need a Context. This is way I suggested you to use another module  (AppModule) that inject the application context. [Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2) you can find its implementation

Comment: Good. Thanks a lot.